# matlab Attempted to access rel(9508,4); index out of bounds because size(rel)=[9507,8]

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a matrix rel nx8 and a second matrix mx3. I want to check if column 3 of matrix rel contains an 8. If yes, I pass to the second condition: if column 3 of matrix rel is equal to to column 2 of matrix A, go to the third condition and create two additional columns in matrix A with the elements of columns 7 and 8 of matrix rel.

```
n=size(rel)
m=length(A)
 for i=1:n
   for k=1:m
        if rel(i,4)==8
             if rel(i,3)==A(k,2)
                 if (rel(i,2)== A(k,1)) || (rel(i,1)== A(k,1))
                   A(k,4)=rel(i,7);
                   A(k,5)=rel(i,8);
                 end
              end
         end
      i=i+1
   end
```

end

However I get this message error: Attempted to access rel(9508,4); index out of bounds because size(rel)=[9507,8].
Does anybody know how could I fix it?

Comment: There are literally a gazillion "Attempted to access" questions on this site. I assume that you searched and looked at them? So you know you need to debug your code. How would you start? Which line of your code do you think this is happening on? Then, what are the inputs to that line that could possibly cause this issues, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are iterating your variable `i` inside of your `k` for loop. So when you arrive in your `k` loop you are stepping up your original `i` from the first loop to `i+m`. This is the source of your error, as `i+m` becomes greater than `n`.

To see this, gut out your if statements, set `n` and `m` to some reasonable values (like 2 and 3) and just run the loops, keeping track of what happens to `i`.

Comment: ok, now I understand, thank you. Yes, I had a look to the other similar questions.